# How do you show that if a block matrix is diagonalizable, then its diagonal entries are diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $C=\begin{bmatrix}A&*\\0&B\end{bmatrix}$ (where $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices) is diagonalizable, prove that $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable.

Let $f_C(x)$, $f_A(x)$, and $f_B(x)$ be the characteristic polynomials of $C$, $A$, and $B$, respectively. Also, let $m_C(x)$, $m_A(x)$, and $m_B(x)$ be the minimal polynomials of $C$, $A$, and $B$, respectively.

I've proven that $f_C(x)=f_A(x)f_B(x)$, and I know that minimal polynomials divide their corresponding characteristic polynomials, so I eventually proved that $m_A(x)$ and $m_B(x)$ both divide $f_C(x)$. I also know that since $C$ is diagonalizable, $m_C(x)$ must be a product of distinct linear polynomials.

Now here is where I'm stuck. If I could somehow prove that $m_A(x)$ and $m_B(x)$ both divide $m_C(x)$, then I can conclude that $m_A(x)$ and $m_B(x)$ are also products of distinct linear polynomials, which would imply that $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable. But how do I do this? Is this even correct in the first place?

Any help would be much appreciated. If there is a completely different way of proving this, I'm all ears too. Thank you!

Comment: By product of distinct linear polynomials, you mean that a product of *relatively prime* linear polynomials, right?

Comment: There's no reason for the linear polynomials to be distinct. You're going to need to involve eigenvectors as far as I can see.

Comment: @Oliver he probably meant distinct *monic* linear polynomials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that $m_A$ divides $m_C$, note that
$$
0 = m_C(C) = \pmatrix{m_C(A) & *\\0&m_C(B)}
$$
so, $m_C(A) = 0$.  It follows that $m_A$ divides $m_C$ (similarly for $m_B$).